# How to put elements in one line with css?

Tags: html, css

I have some text that is interrupted by a tag change. Obviously, the second part of the text begins in a new line. How can I put it in one line? I tried to add `display: inline` to the `<p>`. But this has the effect that the position of 'Name.' changed.

```
<span id="page170" title="170">
    <p class="_10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb"><span class="semibold-semicondensed _idGenCharOverride-1">Name.</span>  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text be</p>
</span>
<span id="page171" title="171">
    <p class="_10_Lesetext_02_Txt"> together Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
</span>
```

[Fiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFubV.png)

**EDIT**

Here you can see how it should look like:

[image: How it should look like]

Comment: First of all, you need to stop writing invalid HTML - you can not nest `p` into `span`.

Comment: Voting to close as typo (invalid HTML).

Comment: Okay. Why isn't this possible?

Comment: @chocolatecake: Because HTML has rules. The content of [`span` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) is defined as [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1), like sentence text, emphasis elements, that kind of thing. But [`p` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) aren't allowed in phrasing content, they're [flow content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1) (structural things like paragraphs). You can't put a paragraph in a sentence, it's backward.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `div` instead of `span` because `span` can't contain `p` as child then do this:

**UPDATE** wrap it in a block element, and give a `text-indent` and then add some `padding-left`

```css
article {
  text-indent: -2em;
  padding-left: 50px
}
div,
p {
  display: inline
}
p._10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb {
  font-size: 0.783em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.223;
  margin-left: 9px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  orphans: 1;
  page-break-after: auto;
  page-break-before: auto;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  widows: 1;
}
p._10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb_tab {
  font-size: 0.783em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.223;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  orphans: 1;
  page-break-after: auto;
  page-break-before: auto;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  widows: 1;
}
p._10_Lesetext_02_Txt {
  font-size: 0.783em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.223;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  orphans: 1;
  page-break-after: auto;
  page-break-before: auto;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  widows: 2;
}
span.semibold-semicondensed {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro Semibold", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
}
span._idGenCharOverride-1 {
  font-size: 0.958em;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div id="page170" title="170">
    <p class="_10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb"><span class="semibold-semicondensed _idGenCharOverride-1">Name.</span> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text be</p>
  </div>
  <div id="page171" title="171">
    <p class="_10_Lesetext_02_Txt">together Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: That's nearly the solution! Is it possible that the indentation of the next will not be deleted?

Comment: ya it is of course I just deleted because I thought you didn't want that blank space on the left

Comment: Ah, okay :D. I forgot to mention it :D

Comment: I've added to the answer, play as you wish

Comment: Thanks! 'Name.' should be left and the next line needs an indention. So, otherwise :)

Comment: That looks great! Thank you so much, dippas!

Answer (score 1):

just add

```
span,p{
  display:inline;
  }
```

to your style sheet ,it works fine.

```css
span,p{
  display:inline;
  }
p._10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb {
  font-size: 0.783em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.223;
  margin-left: 9px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  orphans: 1;
  page-break-after: auto;
  page-break-before: auto;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: -9px;
  text-transform: none;
  widows: 1;
}
p._10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb_tab {
  font-size: 0.783em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.223;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  orphans: 1;
  page-break-after: auto;
  page-break-before: auto;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent:-9px;
  text-transform: none;
  widows: 1;
}
p._10_Lesetext_02_Txt {
  font-size: 0.783em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.223;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  orphans: 1;
  page-break-after: auto;
  page-break-before: auto;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  widows: 2;
}
span.semibold-semicondensed {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro Semibold", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
}
span._idGenCharOverride-1 {
  font-size: 0.958em;
}
```

```html
<span id="page170" title="170">
    <p class="_10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb"><span class="semibold-semicondensed _idGenCharOverride-1">Name.</span>  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text be</p>
</span>
<span id="page171" title="171">
    <p class="_10_Lesetext_02_Txt"> together Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the 'name' still goes to the right

Comment: @chocolatecake name ??,please describe your problem,i will help you

Comment: The bold text 'Name.' at the beginning of the text. It should stay there.

Comment: @chocolatecake check now

Comment: 'Name.' still goes to the right. It should be on the left side and the next line needs an indention.

Comment: @chocolatecake on my browser i get it on the left side, probably the problem with the browser you using.

Comment: It looks the same in firefox, Sarafi and Chrome. May I didn't explain it well. 
'Right' doesn't mean `float: right. I mean that it is not at the left side, but has a little indention. I edited my answer. Maybe it is a little bit clearer, now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding the following code to your CSS:

```
span, p {
    display: inline;
}
```

You can see a working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/b5ou6gsf/2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the bold text 'Name.' still goes to the right.